# How to remove white space in FedEx ZPL labels?

Tags: label, fedex, zpl

I'm using FedEx web service in our application. FedEx label received in web service response. The labels are printing shifted down, There is a blank space at the top of the label.

```
        request.RequestedShipment.LabelSpecification = new LabelSpecification();
        request.RequestedShipment.LabelSpecification.ImageType = ShippingDocumentImageType.ZPLII; 
        request.RequestedShipment.LabelSpecification.ImageTypeSpecified = true;
        request.RequestedShipment.LabelSpecification.LabelFormatType = LabelFormatType.COMMON2D;
        request.RequestedShipment.LabelSpecification.LabelStockType = LabelStockType.STOCK_4X6;
```

[Label Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0goU.png)

How can I remove that white space?

Comment: What make/model printer?

Comment: Is it a matter of the printers origin not being set correctly? If you change the origin of the printer using the ^LH command that might help. See the ZPL documentation.

Comment: did you find the answer?